# How to modify data before diplaying it in DevExpress Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, report

I have several pages that contains a Report in each one, and I used a base class for these pages called `ReportBasePage`.

The Report shall view some date fields in it beside other fields, and now I want to do some modifications on the report parameters before displaying them on the report. How could I do that?

In other words, **I want to change the date format from the base page before being displayed on the report.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the date in different format, you can change the FormatString of the control that is displaying the date value (for example XRLabel). Set the FormatString to your desired date format (for example "{0:dd-MM-yy}")

If you need to change the value (not the format) of the report parameters, you can do it using the XtraReport event "ParametersRequestSubmit".

Regards.

Comment: The problem my friend that I want to control the Date Format in the base class, because I have hundreds of reports and report pages, and I can't go to each one and change the displayed date.

Comment: You can create 2 parameters, one of type Date and one of type String.
The parameter of type string should not be visible.

Using the XtraReport event "ParametersRequestSubmit" you assign the value of the date paramter to the string parameter (formatted as you want).

In your reports use the value of the string parameter (with the formatted date value) instead of the date parameter.